# VHDL Subtraction results in 'X' in the upper 4-bit of the results, how do I fix this?

Tags: logic, vhdl, digital-logic

I'm trying to implement a division algorithm in vhdl. To do that the first step is to double the amount of bits that are in the dividend and divisor. The next step is to perform a subtraction with these expanded values. When vhdl performs the subtraction it fills the upper bits (the ones that were added on) with 'X', but the result of the lower bits are correct.

Below is my code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Divider is 
generic(
                n : positive := 4    -- bit number of adder
        );

port (
    dividend : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
    divisor : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
    quotient: out std_logic_vector(2*n-1 downto 0);
    remainder: out std_logic_vector(2*n-1 downto 0)
);
end Divider;

architecture archDivider of Divider is
begin
    process (divisor, dividend)
       variable intermediary_divisor: std_logic_vector(2*n-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
      variable intermediary_remainder: std_logic_vector(2*n-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
       variable intermediary_quotient: std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        begin
        intermediary_divisor(2*n-1 downto n) := divisor;
        intermediary_remainder(n-1 downto 0) := dividend;
    --  for i in 0 to n-1 loop
            intermediary_remainder := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(to_integer(unsigned(intermediary_remainder)) - to_integer(unsigned(intermediary_divisor)), 2*n));
    --      if (intermediary_remainder >= 0) then
    --          intermediary_quotient := to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(intermediary_quotient) sll 1);
    --          intermediary_quotient(0) := '1';
    --      else
    --          intermediary_remainder := intermediary_remainder + intermediary_divisor;
    --          intermediary_quotient := to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(intermediary_quotient) sll 1);
    --      end if;
                 intermediary_divisor := to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(intermediary_divisor) srl 1);
    --  end loop;

        quotient <= intermediary_divisor(2*n-1 downto 0);
        remainder <= intermediary_remainder(2*n-1 downto 0);
        end process;
 end archDivider;
```

Currently most of the algorithm is commented out while I try to debug my code and some of the outputs aren't set to what they should be for the actual algorithm, but this is for debugging purposes. What in my code can result in such a weird issue?

Comment: You are trying to do a fixed point division ? Well, even if you double the number of bits you will always get an error (If you do not have powers of 2).

I can take time tomorrow to make a big post about fixed point divisions and floating points ones (And the differences in terms of architecture)

Comment: Its not fixed point division, its integer division. The algorithm I am trying to implement comes from a textbook, so I don't think the issue lies there.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] There's no signal or variable Results. Your question isn't specific. If you're referring to intermediary_divisor, it would appear divisor doesn't have an initial value (and would be "UUUU" which would show up upper 4 bits (for n = 4). You can also get a bounds check error for a negative integer value resulting from integer subtraction, use unsigned subtraction. Adopt a style making your code readable (avoid double line spacing here).

Comment: @user1155120, this is the entire file, there is nothing more in the file. Indeed I am referring to the intermediary divisor variable, which is outputted through the quotient variable. Furthermore, I thought that `:= (others => '0');` would at least fill up the upper bits with 0s, does that not work?

Comment: I'm using quartus ii, I detected this using the vwf file. How did you get the print out that you attached? For example when the dividend is 7 and the divisor is 2 in intermediary_divisor it should be 00100000 and in intermediary_remainder it should be 00000111. The subtraction should esult in 11100111, which the algorithm should detect as less than 0.

Comment: intermediary_divisor and intermediary_remainder are variables, I thought variables in vhdl work in process like variables in any other language.

Comment: When I comment out the subtraction and just assign the variables to the value they should be initialized to and output that from the circuit all 2n bits are used. Its only when the subtraction occurs that 'X' is being outputted. That means that some point in the circuit before the subtraction vhdl knows all the 2n values in the variables. According to numerous websites vhdl variables are like variables in any other language which led me to believe I can write to them multiple times. If not what language contruct can I use to allow me to do that?

Comment: Your question code doesn't appear to reproduce your results. The to_unsigned conversion from integer subtraction produces a bounds error for a negative integer subtraction result for divisor 7, dividend 2. Switching the variables to signed or unsigned will produce X's for the subtraction but unsigned won't work for the commented out if statement >= 0 (else negative) for division. The cure for X's is to assign the other half of intermediary_remainder all zeros (or sign) when assigning dividend. Otherwise 'U's from dividend produce 'X's in numeric_std subtraction that will persist.

Comment: When I force the values 7 and 2 respectively on signals dividend and divisor, I have the results 0001000 and 00000111 respectively for quotient and remainder. Is it the results you are expecting ?

Comment: what you have is a combinational loop. And your synthesis tool should have told you .

Comment: What is the question here? How to implement division? Or the reasoning for the X's? Is the commented section of the code included in the discussion? Can you get more specific? PS. No @mfro, there is no combinational loop there.

Comment: @rascob: I think there is. At least when it comes to hardware (where the sensitivity list is basically ignored).

The code infers - using variables in an unclocked process - an adder whose output is fed back to its input. 

That's what I call a combinational loop ;)

Comment: @mfro no! That's the point of using **variables** instead of **signals** for such loops (e.g. successive additions of a variable with itself should generate adders in series). Try it for yourself on a decent synthesis tool :)

Comment: @rascob: I guess you should look more carefully. And, btw., unless you don't consider latest Quartus or ISE 'decent', they agree with me.

Comment: @mfro sounds interesting. Can you share the code that produces those comb loops?

Comment: @rascob: it's an exact 1:1 copy of what the TO posted above.

Comment: @mfro wow, you're right! It looks like Quartus gets confused because at the initial assignment, only a slice of the vector variables are assigned a value. Try replacing `intermediary_remainder(n-1 downto 0) := dividend;` with `intermediary_remainder := (n-1 downto 0 => '0') & dividend;` which behaves in the same way but synthesizes properly in Quartus.

Comment: "gets confused" appears a bit misleading to me. Quartus (and, btw, ISE does the same thing) just infer what the code (maybe not the coder) was asking for.